# Should I refer to myself as a PhD candidate or a researcher as an author of a paper?

Tags: publications, journals

My paper was accepted in a reputed journal. As I have to submit an author biography, I was wondering whether I should refer to myself as a PhD candidate or better say a researcher?
I feel that a paper authored by a PhD candidate may not receive the same attention since some people would see students as not that competent yet.

Comment: Do you have an official designation at your organization?

Comment: I did not get what you mean. I'm officially enrolled in a PhD program ( 2nd year now).

Comment: You are training to be a researcher, so I’d go with researcher. You could get a job as an engineer before you’ve done any engineering, and you’d still call yourself an engineer. Whatever you want to be, go with that, it will empower and guide your actions in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @GrayLiterature "get a job as an engineer before you’ve done any engineering, and you’d still call yourself an engineer" In some places that would be a crime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_and_licensure_in_engineering

Comment: "a paper authored by a PhD candidate may not receive the same attention" This does not make sense because a very large portion of papers are authored by PhD students.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter, it's a bio.

Describe who you are. Do you see yourself as a PhD student or a researcher?

Be careful because "PhD candidate" has additional meaning some places vs others, and you don't want to misuse it if it doesn't apply to you (it does not mean "PhD student" everywhere).

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the bio is not necessary. I would not add it then. Thank you for the answer